# Где лучше разместить документацию к проекту на github?

Tags: документация, github-pages, doxygen

Ку.

Сгенерировал документацию для проекта в doxygen, хочу закинуть на github pages. Вопрос: как это сделать логичнее и правильнее?

Создать папку "documentation" в репозитории и пихнуть сгенерированные файлы документации (.html, .css, картинки) в неё? Или может создать отдельный репозиторий под документацию и на его основе создать страницу?

Answer (score 0):

Документация относящаяся к проекту - должна находиться в одном репозитории.
Вы можете воспользоваться общепринятой практикой назвать дирректорию `docs` и разместить в ней сгенерированные файлы. В этой дирректории могут также находиться UML диаграммы и HTTP запросы.

При этом описание проекта следует разместить в файле README.md в корне репозитория

Comment: Окей, спасибо!
А если такой вариант - создать ветку чисто под документацию, сделать по этой ветке github page и в основной ветке проекта в README.md указать ссылку на эту страницу с документацией? Или это будет использование автомата для открытия консервной банки?

Comment: Вы можете использовать отдельную ветку для работы с документацией и ее обновлениями, при этом сливать ее в `master`.
Если вы работаете над проектом в одиночку и документация потребуется только заказчику как ваш результат работы, тогда можете лить сразу в мастер и "сбережете патроны"